# List data frames different lines - bad performance

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, comparison

I have two data.frames that are expected to be identical (ordered by PK).
I need to list the different lines - any line with any different column.
The last function shown does the job, but takes too long.
@Gilles offered a much better solution, using apply. This is a modified version to display alternating rows (`df1`,`df2`).

Good performance solution (0.1 second!):

```
compDfOrden=function(df1,df2){ 
  df1=df1[complete.cases(df1),]
  df2=df2[complete.cases(df2),]
  df1d=data.frame();  df2d=data.frame()
  if(nrow(df1)!=nrow(df2)){cat('different lines number'); return()
  } else linhas=nrow(df1)
  if(ncol(df1)!=ncol(df2)){cat('different columns number'); return()
  } else colunas=ncol(df1)
  different <- apply(df1 != df2, 1, any)
  difRows=sum(different)
  if(difRows>0){
    df1d=cbind(df='df1',l=1:difRows,df1[different,])
    df2d=cbind(df='df2',l=1:difRows,df2[different,])
    dfd=rbind(df1d,df2d)
    dfd=with(dfd,dfd[order(l,df),])[,-2]
  } else dfd=data.frame()
  return(dfd)
}
  }
tz1=Sys.time()
z=compDfOrden(t1,t2)
Sys.time()-tz1
Time difference of 0.1000059 secs
nrow(z)/2
9303
nrow(t1)
9305
row.names(z)=NULL
head(z,2)
   df   c1    c2 c3 c4 c5       c6       c7       c8       c9      c10      c11      c12    c13    c14       c15  c16   c17
1 df1 1390 ALPA4  F  8  1 0.224000 0.206000 0.275000 0.277000 16.09403 -18.9546 20.75508 2.7116 -1.926 0.4254945 10.3 11.08
2 df2 1390 ALPA4  F  8  1 0.223516 0.205639 0.274514 0.277207 16.10096 -18.9821 20.75508 2.6829 -1.926 0.4254945 10.3 11.08
    c18  c19      c20      c21
1 10.61 2.02 6.931000 2.920000
2 10.61 2.02 6.930612 2.921772
```

Poor performance solution (2.6 minutes):

```
compDfOrden=function(df1,df2){
  df1d=data.frame() 
  if(nrow(df1)!=nrow(df2)){cat('no. linhas diferentes'); return()
  } else linhas=nrow(df1)
  if(ncol(df1)!=ncol(df2)){cat('no. colunas diferentes'); return()
  } else colunas=ncol(df1)
  for(x in 1:linhas){
    for(y in 1:colunas){ 
      if(df1[x,y]!=df2[x,y]){
    #if(!identical(df1[x,],df2[x,])){
        df1d=rbind(df1d,cbind(df='df1',df1[x,]))
        df1d=rbind(df1d,cbind(df='df2',df2[x,]))
        break()}
    }
  }
  return(df1d)  
}
t1=Sys.time()
z=compDfOrden(df1,df2)
Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 2.584698 mins
nrow(df2)
9305
```

`if(!identical(df1[x,],df2[x,])){...` is worse (2.64 mins).

Comment: why was this question negativated?

Comment: I didn't downvote but it is unclear what you are exactly asking. Especially after your edit to include Gilles' answer. And the title of your question is very generic.

Comment: @UweBlock I was asking for performance gain. I will change title. Gilles answer was perfect and I changed the function to incorporate his idea. I did it cause it can be useful for others searching for the same.

Comment: @Gilles, is it fine to modificate the question to incorporate your idea in the function, showing the great gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight improvement (~3 times faster) like this. However I had to build a matrix with much more lines than yours to to reach a few seconds (maybe you have many columns and/or a less powerful computer ?). My presentation of the data is slightly different but you can adapt it and this should not change the performance a lot.

```
# Reproducible example
df1 <- matrix(rnorm(4000000), ncol = 4)
colnames(df1) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(df1)]
rownames(df1) <- 1:nrow(df1)
df2 <- df1 
df2[2, 3] <- rnorm(1)
df2[6, 1] <- rnorm(1)

comp_test <- function(df1, df2) {
    different <- apply(df1 != df2, 1, any)
    cbind(df1[different,, drop = FALSE], df2[different,, drop = FALSE])
}
```

Time difference and results :

```
> comp_test(df1,df2)
          A          B         C          D         A          B           C          D
2 0.4769979 -0.2693178  0.750328  1.8281688 0.4769979 -0.2693178 -0.06271077  1.8281688
6 0.5396275  0.4195784 -1.865591 -0.5488179 0.5456412  0.4195784 -1.86559051 -0.5488179
> Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 1.606129 secs
> 
> 
> t1=Sys.time()
> compDfOrden(df1,df2)
    df                  V2
A  df1   0.476997924412505
B  df1   -0.26931778399519
C  df1   0.750328023463562
D  df1    1.82816879962394
A1 df2   0.476997924412505
B1 df2   -0.26931778399519
C1 df2 -0.0627107709133403
D1 df2    1.82816879962394
A2 df1   0.539627546788513
B2 df1   0.419578406226185
C2 df1   -1.86559050830151
D2 df1  -0.548817860878508
A3 df2   0.545641208974783
B3 df2   0.419578406226185
C3 df2   -1.86559050830151
D3 df2  -0.548817860878508
> Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 5.664673 secs
>
```

The speed improvement is higher when you have more differences :

```
> df1 <- matrix(rnorm(4000000), ncol = 4)
> df2 <- df1 
> nb_differences <- 3000
> df2[sample(1:length(df2), nb_differences)] <- rnorm(nb_differences)
> 
> 
> t1=Sys.time()
> res <- comp_test(df1,df2)
> Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 1.127508 secs
> 
> 
> t1=Sys.time()
> res <- compDfOrden(df1,df2)
> Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 21.24287 secs
```

Comment: The main consumption was due to number of differences (data frame "write"). With few differences, it drops to seconds. I will try the `apply` function and tell.

Comment: This does not seem to be `CompDfOrden`: it gives `df1` and `df2` alternating.

Comment: the data frames have 21 columns, @Gilles

Comment: Indeed the number of differences change a lot the results of your function. I used CompDfOrden as provided in you question...

Comment: your solution took 0.1s! tks!! (question modified to adopt it)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if this is what you want, but see if this function can help. It is inspired in the answer by [Petr Savicky](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/304830.html) to a question to R-Help asked 27.Feb.2012.

```
setdiffDF <- function(A, B){
    f <- function(A, B)
        A[!duplicated(rbind(B, A))[nrow(B) + 1:nrow(A)], ]
    df1_name <- deparse(substitute(df1))
    df2_name <- deparse(substitute(df2))
    df1 <- f(A, B)
    df2 <- f(B, A)
    df1$df <- df1_name
    df2$df <- df2_name
    rbind(df1, df2)
}
```

Tested, but not with your data, since you have posted none.

Comment: Seems to be much slower than @xm1 function

Comment: @xm1: Check out package `prob`, function `setdiff`.

Comment: Tks, @RuiBarradas. If the function is simple, I prefer to develop than to load a package.